# Making a event variable to draw a line on canvas

Tags: java, events, canvas, swt

Hi im making a little program which can make lines, circles, squares and triangles inside a canvas. All this with a GC event and two points (Sx,Sy) and (Ex,Ey). The event is tirggered when I click inside the canvas and drag a line through it. and it makes the geometric figure choosen between the start point and the end point. All thought when I try to update and move 10 pixels to the right or left, by clicking a button, I need to send a  event which is not null or have the event to draw on the canvas. here is a bit of the code. I have all the SX SY EX and EY as global variables.

```
canvas.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            SX = event.x;
            SY = event.y;

            textSX.setText(Integer.toString(SX));
            textSY.setText(Integer.toString(SY));

            drag = true;
        }
    });

    canvas.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            EX = event.x;
            EY = event.y;

            drag = false;
        }
    });

    canvas.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            if(drag)
            {
                EX = event.x;
                EY = event.y;

                textEX.setText(Integer.toString(EX));
                textEY.setText(Integer.toString(EY));

                canvas.redraw();
            }
        }
    });

    canvas.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            if(drag)
            {
                if(btnLinea.getSelection()){
                    gc = event.gc;

                    crearLinea(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

                }
                if(btnCirculo.getSelection()){
                    gc = event.gc;

                    crearCirculo(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

                }
                if(btnCuadrado.getSelection()){
                    gc = event.gc;

                    crearCuadro(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

                }
                if(btnTriangulo.getSelection()){
                    gc = event.gc;

                    crearTriangulo(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

                }
            }
        }
    });

    MasX.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){

        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            SX += 10;
            EX += 10;
            System.out.println(SX+" "+SY+" "+EX+" "+EY);
            //canvas.redraw();
            System.out.println("Aqui 2");
            //gc.drawLine(SX, SY, EX, EY);
            crearLinea(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

        }

    });
```

If something is not clear please ask so :D Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found how to make the movement happen. I called upon the canvas.redraw() method and made a canvas.addPaintListener(); which is called by the redraw, this method gives me the event Im looking for to update te place were the line use to be. Here is the code

```
canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent event) {
            if(btnLinea.getSelection()){
                gc = event.gc;

                crearLinea(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

            }
            if(btnCirculo.getSelection()){
                gc = event.gc;

                crearCirculo(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

            }
            if(btnCuadrado.getSelection()){
                gc = event.gc;

                crearCuadro(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

            }
            if(btnTriangulo.getSelection()){
                gc = event.gc;

                crearTriangulo(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

            }
        }
    });
```

That is the method. and the button calling this method is this one:

```
MasX.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){

        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            SX += 10;
            EX += 10;
            System.out.println(SX+" "+SY+" "+EX+" "+EY);
            canvas.redraw();
            System.out.println("Aqui 2");
            //gc.drawLine(SX, SY, EX, EY);
            //crearLinea(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

        }

    });
```

Hope this helps the next person who has this problem.